# Перебор массива PHP

Tags: php

Вопрос банальный, но не могу понять как мне разобрать массив на ключи и значения, что-бы потом положить их в 1 переменную и отправить функцией `mail()`

```
   object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
  ["Супермясная 3"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (6) {
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "695"
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["totalPrice"]=>
    int(695)
    ["name"]=>
    string(24) "Супермясная 3"
    ["productSize"]=>
    string(7) "27 см"
  }
  ["Сытные палочки с чоризо"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (6) {
    ["price"]=>
    int(295)
    ["quantity"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(222) "Легкие брусочки тонкого теста, покрытые сыром и начинкой из пикантных колбасок чоризо с соусом Чипотл Саусвест. 8 палочек"
    ["totalPrice"]=>
    int(295)
    ["name"]=>
    string(43) "Сытные палочки с чоризо"
    ["image"]=>
    string(31) "assets/img/zakuski/palochka.jpg"
  }
}
```

Этот массив получился после того как я распарсил `JSON`, длина его может быть любой, как можно его перебрать и выбрать нужные поля для отправки в `mail()`? 
Заранее спасибо!

P.S. изначальный `JSON`

```
{"Супермясная 3":{"price":"695","quantity":"1","description":"","totalPrice":695,"name":"Супермясная 3","productSize":"27 см"},"Сытные палочки с чоризо":{"price":295,"quantity":"1","description":"Легкие брусочки тонкого теста, покрытые сыром и начинкой из пикантных колбасок чоризо с соусом Чипотл Саусвест. 8 палочек","totalPrice":295,"name":"Сытные палочки с чоризо","image":"assets/img/zakuski/palochka.jpg"}}
```

Comment: массив это и так ключ и значение, второй параметр json_decode в true установите, и получите массив а не объекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему все просто:

```
$json = '{"Супермясная 3":{"price":"695","quantity":"1","description":"","totalPrice":695,"name":"Супермясная 3","productSize":"27 см"},"Сытные палочки с чоризо":{"price":295,"quantity":"1","description":"Легкие брусочки тонкого теста, покрытые сыром и начинкой из пикантных колбасок чоризо с соусом Чипотл Саусвест. 8 палочек","totalPrice":295,"name":"Сытные палочки с чоризо","image":"assets/img/zakuski/palochka.jpg"}}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data as $key => $values) {
    // здесь отбираешь что надо
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не массив а объект, чтобы получился массив нужно  `json_decode($jsonString,true);`
А дальше самый простой вариант перебором или любым хелпером для массивов